# What semantic field underlies 即?

Tags: etymology

I can grasp how卩 (“to kneel”) relates to definitions 1-3 below. But how does 皀  + 卩 compound to mean definitions 4-14 that don't relate to food or kneeling and that all differ from each other? Definitions 5 and 7 are the ones that overlap at all!  I screenshot [Yellowbridge](https://www.yellowbridge.com/chinese/character-etymology.php?zi=%E5%8D%B3#).

[image]

[即 - Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%8D%B3)

> ### Glyph origin
>
> Ideogrammic compound (*[會意](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%9C%83%E6%84%8F#Chinese)*): *[皀](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%9A%80#Chinese)* (“ancient round-mouthed food vessel”) + *[卩](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%8D%A9#Chinese)* (“to kneel”) – to come near to eat; to approach.
>
> ### Definitions
>
> 1. † to [come](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/come) [near](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/near) to [eat](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/eat)
> 2. † to [approach](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/approach); to [come](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/come) [near](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/near); to be [near](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/near)
> 3. † to [ascend](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ascend); to [go up](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/go_up); to [assume](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/assume) [office](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/office)
> 4. † [prompted](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prompted) by the [occasion](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/occasion)
> 5. † [though](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/though); [although](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/although)
> 6. † [if](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/if); [assuming](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/assuming)
> 7. † [even if](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/even_if); [even though](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/even_though)
> 8. † [then](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/then)
> 9. † [while](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/while)
> 10. † [as soon as](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/as_soon_as)
> 11. [namely](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/namely); [that is](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/that_is); [to](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/to) [be](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/be) the [same](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/same) [as](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/as); [i.e.](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/i.e.)
> 12. † [promptly](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/promptly); [quickly](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quickly); [immediately](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/immediately); [at once](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/at_once)
> 13. † [at present](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/at_present); [today](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/today)
> 14. A [surname](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/surname)​.

Answer (score 1):

imo, yexxxxxxxxxx and wikxxxxxxx are suitable for beginner only. if you’re interested in etymology, use proper, and better tools; please.

[multi-function chinese character database (漢語多功能字庫)](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/)

it’s maintained by the chinese university of hong kong

[http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=即](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%8D%B3)

read the text in the middle, compare the character in oracle, bronze and seal script.

or, try the [小學堂](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/) , of taiwan

http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=497

read the character in oracle script, make a mental image :)

Answer (score 0):

> 甲金文从「皀」从「卩」，像人跪（卩）于食器前就食之形，本义是就食，引申为接近。
>
> [——汉语多功能词库，香港中文大学](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%8D%B3)