# How does 即 + 使 compound to mean "even"?

Tags: etymology

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english-chinese-traditional/even) translates 'even' as [即使](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%8D%B3%E4%BD%BF), as can be substantiated on [ZDIC.net](https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E5%8D%B3%E4%BD%BF). But what semantic notions underlie 即, 使 with "even"?

[*ABC Chinese–English Comprehensive Dictionary* (2003)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABC_Chinese%E2%80%93English_Dictionary).  I can't access the ["slightly revised through July 2005" ed.](https://wenlin.com/abc%22)

[image]

Comment: 即 2 “assume" alone means "even if". 即使、即便、即或 means the same: "even if/though"

Comment: The basic meaning of 即 is instant(ly).  It makes sense when combine with 使 as above: ask people to do it right now - implying "still not going to work".  Hence "even" or "even though" is it's function.  in 即便 即或： 即 also means "on the spot". Use the convenience/alternate on the spot" -> you still will fail.

Comment: See also [this answer to "How did 即 (a person kneeling卩 over food 皀) for shift  to mean 'assume'? Then 'even'?"](https://www.reddit.com/r/ChineseLanguage/comments/yb0rmi/comment/itoaxig/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) at Reddit, and [What semantic field underlies 即?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/39062/8099).

Answer (score 3):

- [即](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/1055/) = assume
- 使 =  make it
- 即使 = assumedly make it (literal meaning)
- [即使 ... 也] =  [assumedly make it .... still ]

Apply the logic in the following sentence:

1. 有錢不賣 = have money, not sell
2. 有錢(也)不賣 = have money  (still) not sell -- *也 is implied*
3. (即使)有錢也不賣 - (assumedly make it that) you have money, I still won't sell --  *即使 is implied*
4. **即使**有錢**也**不賣 = **even** you have money. I **still** won't sell it to you

> "即使" literally means "assumedly make it".  The practical meaning of 即使 (even), is extended from the [即使... 也] structure

Similarly:

就算 = just count as (literal meaning) --> 就算有錢也不賣 (just count it as you have money, I still won't sell it to you) = (even you have money, I still won't sell it to you)

縱使 = allow to make it (literal meaning) --> 縱使有錢也不賣 (allow to make it  that you have money, I still won't sell it to you) = (even you have money, I still won't sell it to you)